# how to get the client secret from okta application using okta java sdk

Tags: java, okta, okta-api

I am using latest okta java sdk

```
application.getCredentials().get("oauthClient");
```

Using above I can able to get the client id, but I need client secret as well.
In `DefaultApplicationCredentialsOAuthClient` class,  I can see the method to get the client secret, but not sure how do I get that

```
public String getClientSecret() {
    return  getString(clientSecretProperty);
}
```

Please help me on this to get the client secret from okta application using Java okta sdk

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: i need the client secret for authentication purpose

Comment: If you're building a Java web app and are able to use OIDC, you shouldn't need the client secret in your code. If you're using Spring Boot, you can use [Okta's Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot).  If you're using Java EE, see [this tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api). You could also use our Java Authn SDK for [servlet authentication](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/07/22/servlet-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for obtaining the **clientSecret** of an application:

```
ApplicationCredentials credentials = application.getCredentials();
String clientSecret = ((DefaultOAuthApplicationCredentials) credentials).getOAuthClient().getClientSecret();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the client secret via secret endpoint.

```
GET {{okta_url}}/api/v1/apps/:appId/credentials/secrets
```